# How to define a class and create an instance of it as one construct

Tags: java

I would like to reduce the following lines of code. It shouldn't be necessary to declare the class and then create an instance of it to get the run method to run. It should be possible to write the code such that you can define the class and create an instance of it as one construct. I still need the runOnUiThread to actually run it but I am looking for a condensed way to combine the class definition and instantiation. I've seen it done somewhere but can't recall how it's done:

```
class OnRunnableCompleted implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
  }
}

OnRunnableCompleted onRunnableCompleted = new OnRunnableCompleted();
runOnUiThread(onRunnableCompleted);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {} });
```

This creates an [*anonymous class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that implements the `Runnable` interface and overrides the abstract `run()` method to be a no-op.

The general form of an anonymous class is

```
new Name(superCtorParam0, superCtorParam1) {
  member0;
  member1;
}
```

where

1. `Name` is the name of an interface or class to extend/implement,
2. `superCtorParam`<sub>0...n</sub> are parameters to `Name`'s constructor
3. `member`<sub>0...n</sub> are the fields, methods, initializers, inner classes of the anonymous class just like in any other class declaration

Comment: That's it. I forgot that it was called "anonymous class".

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
Runnable calculatePI = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){/*calculate pi*/}
}
//Any time you need to calculate pi
runOnUiThread(calculatePI);
```

This reduces the code and prevents the repeated creation of anonymous classes.  In my android development I use this solution quite often.  Works well.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevents the repeated creation of anonymous classes"??? And what exactly is the problem with that even if repeating it was an issue?

Comment: This generates less garbage if your GUI is updated frequently, and simplifies your code logic.  I think Mike has answered your anonymous class query.

Comment: What do you mean by "generates less garbage"? Are you saying that an anonymous class generates more garbage?

Comment: Yes. If created repeatedly and quickly, and your app is real-time (ie. audio, heavy graphics like games) this is a meaningful observation. Otherwise disregaurd.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 8 you can do something like this:

```
yourMethod(() -> System.out.println("RUN!"));
```

Comment: Does the runOnUiThread function exist in JDK 8?  I think its for android.

Comment: It just an example. All the more so OP do not tell nothing about Android, only about java.

Comment: Appreciated, and warranted as Android development was not explicitly specified. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymus class as

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {} });
```